# There is no argument that corresponds to the required formal paramter

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have only just started learning `C#` so excuse this basic question. I am experimenting with C# `inheritance` and want to inherit the `properties` from `Shape` class into the `Rectangle` class. The `Rectangle` class below gives me an error:

> "There is no argument that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'height' of 'Shape.Shape(double.double)'

Is anyone able to tell me why this is happening?

```
class Shape
{
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }

    public Shape (double height, double width)
    {
        Height = height;
        Width = width; 
    }

    public double calculateArea()
    {
        double Area = (Height * Width);
        return Area; 
    }
}
class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public Rectangle(double height, double width)
    {
        Height = height;
        Width = width;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(15, 19);
        double areaOfRectangle = rectangle.calculateArea();
        Console.WriteLine(areaOfRectangle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Shape` class has a single constructor which takes two parameters. You need to pass those two parameters down from your `Rectangle` constructor. Use `public Rectangle(double height, double width) : base(height, width) { }` instead

Comment: I see, thank you for your help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In c#, the `base` keyword is used to access base class members such as `properties`, `methods`, etc. in the derived class. so you have to act like below:

```
public Rectangle(double height, double width) : base(height, width) { ... }
```

for learning more about `base` you can follow [this](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-base-keyword). good luck.

Comment: Thank you for this Hamed thats answered my question.